# Generic Viewmodel Pattern for Master / Detail

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, master-detail

As I understand the Concept behind MVVM within the Viemodel the business Logic is included and/or Things like a Master/Detail relationship of Data exposed to the View

So as I found there are a Lot of ORM Generators like that of telerik a.o for Model's and on the other side designers for xaml etc.
but I could Not found solutions to Build my needed View Models Base if I know I had a simple Master or Master/Detail view and it is based on Classics from the Model I know.

So is there a known Library Out there that makes it more faster to implement Master/Detail viewmodels maybe useing the generic feature of C#?

Basic idea a generic class that I give the model classes I need as master or detail and 
could use this generica as base class for my inherited special implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two possible solutions to this, but there are plenty more.

### Code Snippets

This is not a code generator per say, but a quick and easy solution for making quick view models and such on the fly. There are a few times when we added a model and didn't want to run the generator, so I created a few code snippets of the master view model and detail view model. Then all I would have to do is replace the name in one place, and all the code would change. Microsoft has a pretty [good beginner article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you are new to snippets.

### Code Generator

In the past, I have used [Code Smith's Generator](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator) 
which can take a database with some extended properties defined, and generate all the required views, viewModels, models, etc... This is the more complete solution, giving the ability to generate the whole project vs doing it per file like the above mentioned snippet. However, while code snippets are free, this solution will cost you money.